# ServletOutputStream write in jsp when using struts

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2

I am working with a struts2 web application. Am facing a situation in which I want to display a file (it may be an excel , pdf file or html) in the users browser when he/she clicks on a link.

And the response must be in the form of an open/save dialogue box in the browser.

For that what I had done so far is

1)create an action mapping in struts.xml file.

2)Action  class method will have the content like

```
ServletOutputStream outputStream = null;
outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                byte[] output = (byte[])content;
                response.setContentType(getContentType(format));
                response.setContentLength(output.length);
                outputStream.write(output, 0, output.length);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
```

This code portion will set whatever is the content type, content length and atlast will write the content.

My question is what I need to write in the jsp page for displaying this content.?

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 2):

You either display a JSP page as a result from an action **or** you have the browser download a file. You can't do both. They're sent on the same channel, so to speak.

For a typical example for how to implement downloading files, see [`StreamResult`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html).

But in this case you probably just want to return `ActionSupport.NONE` or `null` from your action since you're setting up the headers and writing the output yourself, see http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/result-configuration.html

If you call

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"rfc2616-quoted-string\"");`
```

the user will be presented with a download dialog, but if you call

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline");`
```

the content will be shown in the browser if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [StreamResult](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StreamResult.html)

Here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-download-file-example/)

Additionally, you can set the StreamResult params in your action class instead of the struts.xml file.

Comment: ok..Is there any way to give that contentType,inputName, contentDisposition as the result of action class inside result tag in struts.xml?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Do you mean you want to set those parameters via code in your action class as opposed to in a struts.xml file? Are you using annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, you need also to set Response header `context-disposition` as "attachment"

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your servlet code

```
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=myfilename.pdf");
```

Comment: Ok..what am asking is what I need to write in jsp page to display that content..just out.println(). right?

Comment: or something more required to display that content..that is what am asking.

Comment: you don't want the user to have option to download the file just display it, right?

Comment: just display the save/open dialogue when the user clicks on this particular link..

Comment: yes this code will display the open/save dialog. Have you tried it?